# How does this variable keep getting updated without new attributions?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a simple service that keeps a list of users:

```
export class UsersService {
  users = ['Max', 'Anna', 'Chris'];

  getUsers() {
    return this.users;
  }

  addUser(username: string) {
    this.users.push(username);
  }
}
```

A component that injects it:

```
export class TestComponent {
  myUsers: any[];

  constructor(private us: UsersService) {
    this.myUsers = us.getUsers();
  }

  addUser(username: string) {
    this.us.addUser(username);
  }
```

And its template with a button that adds a user to the original list:

```
<p><button (click)="addUser('Bob')">Add Bob</button></p>

<p *ngFor="let user of myUsers">{{user}}</p>
```

Considering the constructor is only executed once (I've tested it) how does the `myUsers` variable keep getting updated everytime I add another user? There's no other attribution to it outside the constructor and `myUsers` can't possibly be a pointer since I'm clearly using a method to get a copy of the new value.

Comment: User has to add because you are pushing it to an user array everytime you click on button

Comment: "... can't possibly be a pointer since I'm clearly using a method to get a copy of the new value.". No. You won't get a cloned copy when you call the method you only get a reference to the original array.

Comment: @Saravana I was reading that in JavaScript almost everything is an object, I'm guessing by your comment that even basic data structures like the array are considered objects so when I made the attribution `this.myUsers = us.getUsers();` I ended up with a `myUsers` pointer to `users`. Is that correct? If so, feel free to post your comment as an answer here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do `this.myUsers = us.getUsers();` your `this.myUsers` property ends up with a **reference** to the original `UsersService.users` array, not a copy of the `UsersService.users` array. That is, `TestComponent.myUsers` and `UsersService.users` point to the same array. So if you update `UsersService.users`, `TestComponent.myUsers` gets updated too.